# How do I query for a partition keys that contain a specific substring in dynamoDb?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a partitionKey that is made up 2 strings for e.g. userId:UserName. For e.g 1234:John, 4567:Mark etc. I want to query for all the records that match the substring defined by UserName for e.g. Find all the records that contain "Mark" in the partition key. How do I do this using DynamoDb APIs in Java?

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this is not something that you have to do frequently.

DynamoDB does not support querying by partial hash-key. You would have to use a table scan to iterate over all elements in the table and compare each one for matches.

This is highly inefficient and if you find yourself depending on this type of behavior then you have to revisit your choice of hash-key and your over-all design choices.

For the sake of completeness, the code you're looking for is along the following lines if you're using the Document API:

```
// dynamo returns results in chunks - you'll need this to get the next one
Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;

do {
   ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
       .withTableName("YourTableNameHere")
       .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated);

   ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
   for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){
       // for each item in the result set, examine the partition key
       // to determine if it's a match
       string key = item.get("YourPartitionKeyAttributeNameHere").getS();
       if (key.startsWith("Mark"))
           System.out.println("Found an item that matches *:Mark:\n" + item);
   }
   lastKeyEvaluated = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();
} while (lastKeyEvaluated != null);
```

But before you implement something like this in your application consider choosing a different partition key strategy, or creating a [secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) for your table, or both - if you need to make this type of query often!

As a side note, I'm curious, what benefit do you get by including both user id and user name in the partition key?  The user id would, presumably, be unique for you so why the user name?

Comment: Awesome amount of detail Mike! Just need to add some info about possibly using range keys to solve it, and my answer becomes obsolete...

Comment: Thanks @Chris - I've more or less deliberately omitted the range key detail in part because in this case it doesn't make sense (user id and user name pairs should presumably be unique) and in part because I find the use of range-keys with dynamo to be easily miss-understood and the cause of many scaling headaches

Comment: @MikeDinescu is it possible to query a range of partition keys "efficiently"?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this as you've described in a cost efficient manner. You'll need to `scan` the table, which is expensive and time consuming.

Revisit your choice of key so you are always running queries against full key values instead of substrings.

You might want to consider using a range key - when including a range key, queries can be efficiently run against either just the hash key (returning potentially multiple values), or the combination of hash key/range key (which must be unique).

In this example, if you're always querying on either userId:userName or userName (but *not* userId by itself), then using userName as hash key and userId as range key is a simple and efficient solution.

Comment: Just be careful with range keys because it opens up the possibility of having un-even distribution of keys - ie. a few hash keys with a high number of range keys will very likely cause problems (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions.Scaling and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html)